# Where can I find a good Joseki database?

Tags: go, joseki

I've been wondering about certain positions that arise often. To help me understand them, I would like to study the joseki moves. Since printed joseki dictionaries are out-dated very fast, I'd prefer an electronic database if possible.

Comment: (1 item per answer preferably)

Comment: Should this be CW?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Josekipedia

http://www.josekipedia.com/

This is a kind of wiki for joseki. This system has the big advantage of offering explanations, deviations from joseki and refutations,... But I don't know how complete or accurate it is.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm a top contributor at JP) The sourced variations are accurate, though their description is sometimes off. Nonsourced variations tend to be "reasonable", but not as reliable as, for instance, KJD. Recent variations show up almost instantly, though many of them as "question".

Answer (score 12):

### Kogo's Joseki Dictionary

[Kogo's Joseki Dictionary](http://waterfire.us/joseki.htm) is certainly the best known resource in the west. It's an SGF file that contains a huge list of common and uncommon joseki moves including some comments, some even with the game where they occurred.

It is reliable in general, even though there are some mistakes (that are probably difficult to spot unless you're dan or even high dan level).

KJD is included in [Eidogo online](http://eidogo.com/#kjd), so you don't need to download the SGF anymore.

Comment: This is what [Nick Sibicky](https://www.youtube.com/user/nicksibicky) is recommending.

Answer (score 8):

### Daily Joseki

http://dailyjoseki.com/browse

This joseki database is condensed from a database of pro-games. One problem with this approach is that it doesn't contain any explanations or refutations.

---

It also offers some joseki memorization system, but I never tried it myself.

Comment: Nice idea, but seems to offer little practical value

Answer (score 8):

### Brugo

http://www.brugo.be/

Brugo is probably the only dictionary maintained by pros. It includes a few variations not seen anywhere else and tends to be very reliable (as far as I can confirm this).

There are a few tools (like a joseki quiz) rarely found anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Nice one with discussion of the positions is here:

http://senseis.xmp.net/?Joseki

This page is referred to as a source by Josekipedia.com:

http://senseis.xmp.net/?GendaiJosekiJiten

But I am not actually sure what that is, if it is equal to http://senseis.xmp.net/?Joseki or not.

Comment: The Gendai is one of many sources for both senseis/joseki and josekipedia, but I would be very surprised if anyone actually input all of Gendai's content into either database. Further, those databases contain (tons of) information from elsewhere. So they are certainly not equivalent, but rather supplementary.

Answer (score 0):

I use this one:

http://www.learngo.co.uk/Joseki.php?Sequence=4-4,6-4

This one is the best in the sense that you immediately see how the board will look like afterwards, so you can choose proper Joseki according to your current context. But some Josekis (like 5-3) are unfortunatelly missing there.

Comment: It looks very limited to me; looking at http://www.learngo.co.uk/Joseki.php?Sequence=4-4,6-3,8-3 , after ◯ enters at 3-3 I only see ⬤ blocking at 4-3 (between 3-3 and the kakari), while 3-4 is also a standard variation to close ◯ into the corner. While it is nice to see all intermediate stages, it does take an awful lot of screen space to present josekis like this.